# Cython wrap c lib with setup.py build_clib

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, packaging

I decided to refactor my C api wrapper and dive deeper into `libraries` argument in `setuptools.setup`

My project structure is following:

```
|setup.py
|my_pkg
|--|ext_c_lib
|--|--|include
|--|--|--|c_file.h
|--|--|--|c_types.h
|--|--|src
|--|--|--|c_file.c
|--|cy_lib
|--|--|pxd_include
|--|--|--|__init__.py
|--|--|--|c_file.pxd   # functions redefined `with cdef exten from "c_file.h"`
|--|--|--|c_types.pxd  # types redefined `with cdef exten from "c_types.h"`
|--|--|__init__.py
|--|--|utils.pyx       # uses types from c_types.pxd
|--|--|cy_file.pyx     # uses funcs from c_file.c/c_file.pxd
```

utils.pyx:

```
from my_pkg.cylib.pxd_include.c_types cimport SOME_CUSTOM_TYPE
...
```

cy_file.pyx:

```
from my_pkg.cylib.pxd_include.c_file cimport c_func

cdef cy_func(arg):
    arg += 1
    return c_func(arg)
```

setup.py:

```
...
extensions = [Extension('my_pkg.cy_lib.utils', ['my_pkg/cy_lib/utils.pyx']),
              Extension('my_pkg.cy_lib.cy_file', ['my_pkg/cy_lib/cy_file.pyx',
                                                  'my_pkg/ext_c_lib/src/c_file.c']),]

setup(name='my_pkg', ext_modules=extensions, include_dirs=['my_pkg/ext_c_lib/include'])
```

**As `ext_c_lib` does not depend on me and releases quite rare I would like to build it as an external library with `python setup.py build_clib` and then use it in cython files, so I could get rid of pxd files and compiling `c_file.c` once, even if I add separate cython file that uses functions from `c_file.c`. Is that possible?**

I expect something like:
setup.py:

```
...
external = ('external', {'sources': ['my_pkg/ext_c_lib/src/c_file.c']})
extensions = [Extension('my_pkg.cy_lib.utils', ['my_pkg/cy_lib/utils.pyx']),
              Extension('my_pkg.cy_lib.cy_file', ['my_pkg/cy_lib/cy_file.pyx']),]

setup(name='my_pkg', libraries=external,
      ext_modules=extensions, include_dirs=['my_pkg/ext_c_lib/include'])
```

utils.pyx:

```
from external cimport SOME_CUSTOM_TYPE
...
```

cy_file.pyx:

```
from external cimport c_func

cdef cy_func(arg):
    arg += 1
    return c_func(arg)
```

Of course this code does not compile as I get `external.pxd not found`

Comment: Why do you cimport "external" if there is no "external.pxd"?

Comment: I really do not understand what happens behind the scene, when I run build_clib. I only see external.lib file in repo and don't know what to do with it

Comment: You don't have to do anything with external.lib - it will automatically linked. Just keep `c_file.pxd` and `c_types.pxd` around as it is or rename them to `external.pxd` if you like this name better